# Is there any aproach to handle exception on Application level? Android

Tags: android, exception

I am not able to handle all the exceptions in all activities of my package. But I'd like to have a one place (point) where I could handle anything, that extremely finishes the application and send error details to my server by email. Is there such approach? (E.g in WP7 there is `private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a variant of this unhandled exception handler to capture exceptions and log details back to a server.

I took this code and tweaked it:

http://code.google.com/p/android-remote-stacktrace/